# Keep last row the same

Tags: r, shiny

This code utilizes Rshiny. I have code that allows the user to input how many rows he wants. The last row is called TOTAL. I want to make sure that even when the user enters x amount of rows, the TOTAL row should still be at the end.

Whenever I add new rows, it always says "NA.1", "NA.2", "NA.3", etc. Below is my code:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

Apple <- c(1,2,3,4)
Boy <- c(2,4,6,8)
Cat <- c(3,5,7,9)
Dog <- c(8,9,11,14)

ABCD <- data.frame(Apple, Boy, Cat, Dog)
new_ABCD <- c(sum(Apple), sum(Boy), sum(Cat), sum(Dog))

ABCD <- rbind(ABCD,new_ABCD)
row.names(ABCD)[row.names(ABCD) == "1"] <- "Official Baseline FTE"
total <-row.names(ABCD)[row.names(ABCD) == nrow(ABCD)] <- "TOTAL SUM"

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("User Settings"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       numericInput(inputId = "alpha", label="Enter number of alphabet types:",min = 1, max = 25, value = 5)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("ABCD", rHandsontableOutput("ABCD"))
        )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, server) {
  output$ABCD <- renderRHandsontable({
    num_of_alpha <- input$alpha
    rhandsontable(ABCD[1:num_of_alpha,])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
    
    if (input$alpha > 0 && input$alpha <= length(ABCD$Apple)){
       new_ABCD <- c(sum(ABCD[1:input$alpha,'Apple']), 
                               sum(ABCD[1:input$alpha,'Boy']), 
                               sum(ABCD[1:input$alpha,'Cat']), 
                               sum(ABCD[1:input$alpha,'Dog']))
       
       ABCD <- rbind(ABCD,new_ABCD)
       row.names(ABCD)[row.names(ABCD) == "1"] <- "Official Baseline FTE"
       total <-row.names(ABCD)[row.names(ABCD) == nrow(ABCD)] <- "TOTAL SUM"
    } 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The code which would add rows to object `ABCD` never executes because it is contained in a block of code that observes an event for an input that does not exist in the user interface (  `observeEvent(input$runButton, { ...` ).

Comment: I would also suggest maybe using a different id for the tabPanel `ABCD` and the data.frame you call `ABCD` (e.g. `ABCD_df` or something) for the sake of clarity